# HTTP header for indicating required stylistic property for the response body

Tags: json, rest, http, http-headers, rfc

What HTTP header should I use for specifying stylistic properties of an HTTP response, specifically the case of keys in a JSON object? A note: I am developing a REST API where I would like clients to provide an expected case, for example `camelCase` or `snake_case`.

When `camelCase` is specified a response would look like:

```
{
  "peopleUrl": "…",
  "postsUrl": "…"
}
```

When `snake_case` is specified a response would look like:

```
{
  "people_url": "…",
  "posts_url": "…"
}
```

The headers I’ve been looking at are `Expect` and `Prefer`. `Expect` is described as mandatory configurations a server must comply with or error, and `Prefer` is described as optional configurations. The specific syntax I was looking at is:

```
Expect: case=camel
```

or:

```
Prefer: case=camel
```

Currently, I’m feeling like `Expect` is the best because it requires the configuration. However, while in [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.20) an extension mechanism for `Expect` is provided, however in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1) this extension mechanism was removed and only the `100-continue` field is allowed (scroll to the next page to see the note providing the warrant). The `Prefer` header was specified in [RFC 7240](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240) and *does* appear to have an extension mechanism.

Which header is best for this configuration option? Am I looking in the wrong direction with `Expect` and `Prefer`?

Comment: _"I would like clients to provide an expected case"_ - **why?** Just document one casing, and let your clients stick to that... Anyway, as you can read in RFC 7240, you'll have to register `Prefer` extensions with IANA.

Comment: When you have an API which needs to serve data to multiple different platforms, it's helpful to let them choose which format they want. A JS client may want `camelCase` whereas a PHP client might want `snake_case`. Even if this is a bad idea, finding an appropriate header is still a valid question.

Comment: You're the service provider, you determine the format. I'm not saying it's an invalid question, just a silly one. Don't forget about the overhead this will cause on your side. Anyway there's no existing header you can leverage to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments indicate, there probably isn't an existing HTTP header name, defined in the HTTP RFCs, which would cover/handle your use case.  Using `Expect` or `Prefer`, with well-defined semantics that don't quite cover your needs, may lead to more pain/frustration than you'd like; those headers might be handled specially by existing clients, servers, and proxies in ways that you do not want/expect.

That said, there is nothing preventing you from using your own custom `X-` header for requests *and* responses, *e.g.* `X-JSON-KeyStyle`:

```
GET /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
X-JSON-KeyStyle: camel
...
```

And then your response would indicate the style used in the returned data:

```
HTTP1/1 200 OK
...
X-JSON-KeyStyle: camel
...
```

By specification, any header names prefaced with `X-` are deliberately not handled/covered, and are for uses such as this.  With this approach, then, you would only need document your custom HTTP header, for use by clients of your REST API.

Hope this helps!